# How to add an image for checkbox item in google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

With Google Apps Script, how can I add an image to a checkbox item? When I create the form manually, I can easily add multiple choices as checkbox item and attach image to each choice. How I can do this with scripting?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there is no option to do this. It was raised as an issue to Google back in 2017. If you go to [this link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765518) you can mark this issue as a favorite (click star) and try to generate more attention from Google developers.