# Moving an item from one Google form to a new Google form using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

When editing a Google form manually, you can usually click on an item, and on the side appears a menu, which includes the button "import questions". This button is very useful for me as it allows me to collect questions from past Google forms and import them to new Google forms.

But I'm looking through the Forms documentation, and I can't figure out how to do this via Google apps script programatically.

Here is the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form

The closest thing to what I want is the .moveItem() method, which moves an item from one spot in a form to another. But it only works within the same form. I want to know if I could do it across forms. And ideally, instead of moving the item, it would make a copy of the item in the new form.

I considered the .getItems() method, but there doesn't seem to be a general .addItem() method I could use on the new form. Would I have to go through the painstaking process of having to identify each item type, and specify how the details of each one should be copied to the new form, including things like point values of a question and whether or not the question is required?

I want to import from forms that have all kinds of content: video, images, multiple choice questions, grid questions, number scale questions, etc. I feel that if I have to specify the details of each item type, it would take too long, and I would be bound to miss something or run into an error that may be impossible to solve. Is there not an easier way?

And if specifying each item type is what I have to do to import everything properly, has someone else created that code already that I can re-use?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

In the current stage, unfortunately, it seems that [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms) cannot copy all items. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67881474/7108653), [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67066226/7108653) [Ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64236582/7108653). And, unfortunately, `moveItem` can be used for the same Google Form as you say.

#### Workaround:

In your situation, as a workaround, how about copying the source Google Form? And, when there are some items you want to remove, you can remove them. I thought that this process can be achieved by Google Apps Script.

But, I'm not sure about your actual Google Form. So I'm not sure whether this is a suitable method.

#### Future:

Recently, Google Forms API was announced. [Ref](https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/10/announcing-google-forms-api_01768004272.html) When this API got to be able to be used, your goal might be able to be achieved by retrieving the object from Google Form. Unfortunately, I'm still not sure about the detail of it.